# "Parse error on input ->" in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am writing a function that takes a list of dates (currently in form (Year,Month,Day) where each is an Int: (Int,Int,Int)) and a month (as an Int) and returns the number of times that month appears in the list of dates.

I am getting an error: "parse error on input ->" regarding my first '->' in the function signature:

```
numberInMonth [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
numberInMonth ((y,m,d) : rst) month = 
   if y == month then 1 +(numberInMonth rst) 
   else numberInMonth rst
```

Any thoughts as to why that's not parsing?

Comment: You need to put `::` after the name of the function in the function signature.

Comment: Realized I forgot the :: after numberInMonth

Comment: Willem, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You're just missing the `::` in your type signature.

```
--------------|
--            V
numberInMonth :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> Int -> Int
numberInMonth ((y,m,d) : rst) month = 
   if y == month then 1 +(numberInMonth rst) 
   else numberInMonth rst
```